# Empty date field becomes today's date

Tags: datetime

I have a date field, and I want it to be possible for this to be empty. How it works now is that if you don't enter a value, it takes today's date. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happens because the [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter returns the current date for null values / empty strings.

> If the value passed to the date filter is null, it will return the current date by default.

To work around this, you would add a conditional.

```
{% if entry.myDate %}
    Date: {{ entry.myDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
{% endif %}
```

Another way to do this is to use a [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

```
{{ entry.myDate ? entry.myDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

Comment: for completeness `{{ entry.myDate ? entry.myDate|date('Y-m-d') : 'XYZ' }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new filter to twig that returns an empty string if the date is null or '0000-00-00', or if not reverts to Twig's built in date filter.
Here I've called it 'dateInclEmpty' *(trying to think of a better name)*, you can otherwise use it in the same way as the existing date filter.

```
$filter = function(Twig_Environment $env){
    return new Twig_SimpleFilter('dateInclEmpty', function ($date,$format,$timezone) use($env){
        if (is_null($date) || $date == '0000-00-00'){
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return twig_date_format_filter($env,$date,$format,$timezone);
        }
    });
};
$twig->addFilter($filter($twig));
```

*(Thanks for the advice Lindsey, let's see if this is any better :-P)*

Comment: -1 Hacking the core is never a good idea :(

Comment: I've made it as a new filter instead, hopefully less hacky

Comment: Much better! :)

Answer (score 1):

For DateTime:

```
{{ entry.myDate =="0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? "" : entry.myDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

For Date :

```
{{ entry.myDate =="0000-00-00" ? "" : entry.myDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
```